# SOAP Object referred by 2 others and serialized as 2 different

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

This is a client generated from a wsdl. When I send it to my server, it gets 4 different object with the type A4.:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A4 a41 = new A4();
        A4 a42 = new A4();
        A4 a43 = new A4();
        a41.setName("a41");
        a42.setName("a42");
        a43.setName("a43");

        A2 a2 = new A2();
        a2.getA4ListInA2().add(a41);
        a2.getA4ListInA2().add(a42);

        A3 a3 = new A3();
        a3.getA4ListInA3().add(a42);
        a3.getA4ListInA3().add(a43);


        A1 a1 = new A1();
        a1.setFirst(a2);
        a1.setSec(a3);

        try {
            new Service05Service().getService05Port().count(a1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } `enter code here`
    }

}
```

I dont think its important, but I'm using JAX-WS on an IBM WebSphere 8. In my opinion it doesn't depend on the serializer of the JAXB implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A4 objects are marshaled, JAXB parser cannot distinguish between those elements, whether they are unique and represent same object or not. As stated in [documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_4_3_1-Assembling-Data-with-Links-ID-IDREF.html):

> There will be duplicated objects when the unmarshalled data is
>   transferred into application objects.

You might modify you xsd schema to specify A4 element ID and IDREF's to that particular element, so that JAXB parser could unmarshall message as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser... btw its kinda strange for me, that its like unhandled.